# In python mpmath v. 0.19, the invertlaplace() command can't be found

Tags: python, mpmath

I've [installed mpmath release 0.19](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/setup.html) in Anaconda on my Windows computer and am using Spyder. I ran runtests() and everything was listed as OK. I can't get the 2017 invertlaplace() function to work, though. It seems  that python can't find the command, because I get the error: 
NameError: name 'invertlaplace' is not defined

Any ideas ?

The code I ran is pretty much what the [documentation](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/inverselaplace.html) has:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 15; mp.pretty = True
tt = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10] #evaluation points
fp = lambda p: 1/(p+1)**2
ft = lambda t: t*exp(-t)
invertlaplace(fp,tt[1],method='talbot')
ft(tt[2]),ft(tt[2])-invertlaplace(fp,tt[2],method='talbot')
print('The numerical inverse laplace transform  of fp at .001 is ', 
ft(tt[0]),ft(tt[0])-invertlaplace(fp,tt[0],method='talbot'))
```

Comment: Link the documentation please.

Comment: I edited the original posts to add a couple of links.

Comment: What line does it fail on?

Comment: hmm.. it seems to work fine for me, try installing it with pip: `pip install mpmath`

Comment: I did try pip install mpmath even before posting my question, and it seemed to install fine--- but I get the same error.  I've tried two separate computers, too. By now, I do see that the command works on my university's central research computer (Unix?), just not my PC's.

Comment: Yeah, there is a `windows` installing method on that doc. I assume you've tried that?

Comment: yep.  Oh-- and I don't think it listed a line number, but it seems it fails when it tries to use  the invertlaplace() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade mpmath. You can do this with: pip3 install --upgrade mpmath